# Excel data not populating into web form

Tags: java, selenium

I got a query, I do have a scenario where I need to read the data from xsls and populate the content into web form via selenium web driver,but when I do that, in the web form not populating my data but instead it prints "row 2 or column Addressline1 does not exist in xls", that's the data populating in my web form here's the code below

```
package com.DatadriveTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.excel.utility.Testutil;

public class Readxldatatocards
{

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod

        public void setup() {

        System.setProperty( "webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe" );
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout( 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://mt-bun-app02:9080/CMSBackOffice/cardtype");


    }

    @DataProvider

    public Iterator<Object[]> getTestData(){
       ArrayList<Object[]> testData= Testutil.getDataFromExcel();
       return testData.iterator();
   }




    @Test(dataProvider="getTestData")

    public void CardRegTest(String Title, String Surname, String Forename, String Gender, String DateofBirth, String Addressline1, String Addressline2,
            String Postcode, String DisabilityStatus, String Disabilityduration, String Medicaldate) {

        //Enter data

        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("ZAMEER");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Password2019");
        driver.findElement(By.id("actionLogon")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bottom']/a[@href='addnewcardholder'][contains(text(),'Add new customer')]")).click();

        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='customerTitle']")));
        select.selectByVisibleText("Mr");

        driver.findElement( By.xpath("//input[@id='customerSurname']")).clear();
        driver.findElement( By.xpath("//input[@id='customerSurname']")).sendKeys(Surname);


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='customerForename']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='customerForename']")).sendKeys(Forename);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='genderTable field']//span[1]//input[1]")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='customerDob']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='customerDob']")).sendKeys(DateofBirth);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='locationAddress1']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='locationAddress1']")).sendKeys(Addressline1);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='locationAddress2']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='locationAddress2']")).sendKeys(Addressline2);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='locationAddrPostcode']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='locationAddrPostcode']")).sendKeys(Postcode);

        Select select1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='customerDisability']")));
        select1.selectByVisibleText("Severe Walking Disability");

        Select select2= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='Disability duration']")));
        select2.selectByVisibleText("1 Year");

        driver.findElement( By.xpath("//input[@name='customerMedical']")).clear();
        driver.findElement( By.xpath("//input[@name='customerMedical']")).sendKeys( Medicaldate);

        //upload photo image
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='photoImage']")).click();

        WebElement UploadImg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='photoImage']"));
        UploadImg.sendKeys("D:\\Tulips.jpg");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='actionUpload']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id='Accept']")).click();
    }


    @AfterMethod

    public void teardown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

And here the excel utility class

```
package com.excel.utility;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Testutil
{
    static Xls_Reader reader;

    public static ArrayList<Object[]> getDataFromExcel(){

        ArrayList<Object[]> myData = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        try {
            reader = new Xls_Reader("D://Merseytravelezamples.xlsx");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int rowNum =2; rowNum <= reader.getRowCount("Sheet1"); rowNum++) {

            String Title = reader.getCellData("Sheet1","Title", rowNum);
            String Surname = reader.getCellData("Sheet1", "Surname", rowNum);
            String Forename = reader.getCellData("Sheet1", "Forename", rowNum);
            String Gender = reader.getCellData("Sheet1", "Gender", rowNum);
            String DateofBirth = reader.getCellData("Sheet1", "Date of Birth", rowNum);
            String Addressline1 = reader.getCellData("Sheet1", "Addressline1", rowNum);
            String Addressline2 = reader.getCellData("Sheet1", "Addressline2", rowNum);
            String Postcode = reader.getCellData("Sheet1", "Postcode", rowNum);
            String Disabilitystatus = reader.getCellData("Sheet1", "Disabilitystatus", rowNum);
            String Disabilityduration = reader.getCellData("Sheet1", "Disabilityduration", rowNum);
            String Medicaldate = reader.getCellData("Sheet1", "Medicaldate", rowNum);


            Object ob[] = {Title, Surname, Forename, Gender, DateofBirth, Addressline1, Addressline2, Postcode, Disabilitystatus, Disabilityduration, Medicaldate };
            myData.add(ob);
        }

        return myData;


    }





}
```

Comment: At what line are you getting this `row 2 or column Addressline1 does not exist in xls`? Try to use `rowNum <=reader.getRowCount("Sheet1")` instead of `rowNum <= reader.getRowCount("Sheet1")`. Check data is there or not in the excel and try by closing the excel while reading the data.

Comment: my getting that "row 2 or column...." in my text input fields of web form (surname text input suppose to read name from excel but above thing is reading

Comment: and i tried the way u mentioned, it opens the web page but  giving blank input into the text fields

Comment: Are you getting any error when it is sending the blank input into the input text fields?

Comment: below is the error shows in console

Comment: FAILED: CardRegTest("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")

Comment: when i changed my excel path error as below

Comment: FAILED: CardRegTest("row 2 or column Title does not exist in xls", "row 2 or column Surname does not exist in xls", "row 2 or column Forename does not exist in xls", "row 2 or column Gender does not exist in xls", "row 2 or column Date of Birth does not exist in xls", "row 2 or column Addressline1 does not exist in xls", "row 2 or column Addressline2 does not exist in xls", "row 2 or column Postcode does not exist in xls", "row 2 or column Disabilitystatus does not exist in xls", "row 2 or column Disabilityduration does not exist in xls", "row 2 or column Medicaldate does not exist in xls")

Comment: Don't change any excel path, provide exact and absolute path of your excel path there. I think you are not using the data provider correctly, that's why you are getting that error... And what library are you using for retrieving the data from an excel?

Comment: changed i mean i did copied one more copy of the same excel file on desktop with new name and passed the same path , just to double check maybe the file might creating problem, but its not. coming to the point api i am using apache poi api

Comment: can you share the `Xls_Reader ` class code as well?

Comment: i am new here how to share my code

Comment: Edit your answer and append the code at the end like you do normally and comment your changes and submit again...

Comment: i dont c any edit , where can find exactly please

Comment: and by da way Xls_Reader file is generic i downloaded on net

Comment: Ok, no problem. As I mentioned in the one of the above comments of mine, you are not using the data provider correctly. So I will update your code and will post the answer. I will update you once it is done, give me some time...

Comment: thanks so much buddy , wil wait for you code

Answer (score 0):

As per the discussion, you are not using the data provider correctly and as the result you are getting errors in some other parts of the script.

Suppose if you have the data in excel in the below format :

```
| Username | Password |
| Ali      | Threee   |
| Puppy    | Two      |
| Dummy    | One      |
```

Then you can use the below code to send the Username and Password to some website using the data provider for multiple logins :

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.google.common.base.Function;

public class ReadXLDataToCards {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private ExcelUtility utility;
    private Wait<WebDriver> wait;

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getTestData() throws Exception {
        utility = new ExcelUtility();

        int totalRows = utility.getRowCount("Resources\\InputData.xlsx", "Sheet1");
        int totalColumns = utility.getColumnCount("Resources\\InputData.xlsx", "Sheet1");
        System.out.println("=> Total rows and columns is/are ("+totalRows+", "+totalColumns+")");

        Object[][] data = new Object[totalRows][totalColumns];
        for(int i=0;i<totalRows;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<totalColumns;j++) {
                // Give your excel absolute path with the extension
                data[i][j] = new ExcelUtility().getData("Resources\\InputData.xlsx", "Sheet1", i, j);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    // No need to initialize the ChromeDriver again and again and no need to launch the site again and again so used 'firstTimeOnly'
    @BeforeMethod(firstTimeOnly = true)
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.hackerrank.com/auth/login?h_l=body_middle_left_button&h_r=login");

        wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, StaleElementReferenceException.class);
    }

    // Your test method goes here and this is just a sample working example
    @Test(dataProvider = "getTestData")
    public void test(String userName, String userPassword) {
        WebElement username = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("input-1"));
            }
        });

        WebElement userpass = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("input-2"));
            }
        });

        WebElement signIn = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Log In')]"));
            }
        });

        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys(userName);

        userpass.clear();
        userpass.sendKeys(userPassword);

        signIn.click();
    }
}
```

I haven't separated the classes and have included entire logic in the same class. You can alter this code according to your requirement and this is just sample working example only.

Below is the ExcelUtily class :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelUtility {
    public String getData(String fileName, String sheetName, int rowNumber, int columnNumber) throws Exception {
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileName));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
        return row.getCell(columnNumber).getStringCellValue().trim();
    }

    public int getRowCount(String fileName, String sheetName) throws Exception {
        return WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileName)).getSheet(sheetName).getLastRowNum() + 1;
    }

    public int getColumnCount(String fileName, String sheetName) throws Exception {
        return new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fileName)).getSheet(sheetName).getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    }
}
```

Try to create an excel sheet and provide data as mentioned in the above format and run the script to see the execution so that you will get some idea on how it works...

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts buddy, will give as try and update you

Comment: HI Ali , I tried but really didnt get thru thou, showing errors at private Excelutility and further following of the same

Comment: Ok, the `ExcelUtility` is the separate class and I have added that code in the answer. Check/Try and let me know...

Comment: thanks ya, i did tried but showing in ExcelUtility class "Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileName));" shwoing error :[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.Error: "Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method create(POIFSFileSystem) in the type WorkbookFactory is not applicable for the arguments (File)"

Comment: If you are using maven then you need to include this dependency `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.9</version>
  </dependency>` Or download `poi-ooxml` jar with the version `3.9`

Comment: yep using maven and the dependency u sent is already in their added

Comment: It should be `poi-ooxml` not only `poi` or some other things, cross verify once again...

Comment: i did poi-ooxml exisits, i did double checked

Comment: It is a compilation error so I can't resolve from here, try to resolve by yourself...

Comment: any idea and suggestions how and where to resolve the compilation errors

Comment: If you are using ide, it will show some suggestions to resolve that - try it. I think you are importing the wrong package or not using the correct jar...